# Prove the determinant of A equals 2 times the determinant of B

Tags: matrices, determinant

Question: Prove that

$$ det
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a + b & p + q & u + v \\
        b + c & q + r & v + w \\
        c + a & r + p & w + u \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=2det
\begin{bmatrix}
a & p & u \\
b & q & v \\
c & r & w \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I believe it's related to row operations with determinants but I have no idea where to start. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try the operation "replace the first line $L_1$ by $L_1-L_2+L_3$" and see what it gives you.

Comment: got it, thank you very much!